# Elementary Problem: Opposite and Adjacent Seem to Change From Problem to Problem

Tags: trigonometry

I've read two or three answers here but I suppose I need the idiots guide with paper and crayons to explain it to me.  I can't seem to tell which is opposite and which is adjacent on each problem.  I assume that adjacent is directly below hypotenuse but apparently not.

Any advice is appreciated.  The attached picture is just one many instances of me getting it wrong.

[image: hyp-opp-adj]

Here is the logic I have read to use:
[image: trig-ratio]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us try this picture:

You stand at a position and place a ladder against a wall.

The ladder you place is the hypotenuse.
The wall you face is the opposite side.
The ground you stand on is the adjacent side.

Apply this to your case:

You stand at M (angle M ) ,you place a ladder ML ( hypotenuse) against a wall NL ( opposite side) and you stand on ground MN(adjacent side).

Then the correct answer follows.

Comment: This clicked. Thanks.

Comment: I though it clicked, but (I think I'm using your steps here) why is this wrong now?  [link](https://imgur.com/a/vYSq8Zj)

Comment: You stand at A, your ladder is AB, the wall is BC, the ground is AB. So, cos A = ground/ladder=15/17.

Comment: Thanks for the time.  Sometimes I wonder why I am so stupid at this stuff. Working on not being consistently stupid..

Comment: You are outreaching for help showing that you are a good student eager to learn. You can check this site https://www.mathsisfun.com/links/d-10up-algebra.html for basic maths topics. A lot on fundamental trigs.  Let me know if you need extra help.

Comment: The answer was in my face the whole time but I have so low confidence that I was assuming I just didn't have the brains to figure it out.  It tells you the angle in the question... just like you alluded to.

Comment: Try the exercises in Mathisfun, it gives you answer and explanation. You can redo many times. This will help you master the tipic and build up confidence.

Answer (score 1):

Opposite and adjacent are referenced relative to the angle you are taking the trig value of. Each acute angle is part of a leg (that would be the adjacent side), and across from (not adjacent to) the other leg (that would be the opposite side).

Comment: I still don't understand.  I would post more pictorial examples but the Aleks program I use forced me to change subjects because I got so many incorrect.  Thanks for the time regardless.

Comment: @ArkhamAngel Put your feet at M and look through the interior of the triangle. The triangle's side at your hand is adjacent to the angle you stand at, and the far side is opposite to the angle.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're assuming that Opposite and Adjacent have something to do with the short and long sides of a right-triangle.  (i.e. you're assuming something like "Cosine=Long/Hypotenuse" based on the one defined example.)

But actually Opposite/Adjacent are relative terms (like right/left) that depend on which non-right angle is being asked about.  The "Adjacent" side is "the non-Hypotenuse side that touches the Angle" and "Opposite" is "the far side that doesn't touch the Angle".

In your answers, you were essentially giving cosL=40/41, tanL=9/40, and sinL=9/41 instead of the cosM, tanM, and sinM the book was asking for.

Angle "Theta" in the example is Angle "L" in the problem; the problem set is asking about Angle "M".

Comment: How does one determine which side is the Angle?

Comment: OK, the answer was staring right in my face the whole time.. I feel really dumb sometimes.  it's asking to find tanA cosA sinA A is the angle.

Answer (score 0):

If you're interested in the angle at a vertex $V$ of a right triangle, the adjacent side is the side that goes $V$ to the vertex with the right angle, and the opposite side is the side that goes from the vertex with the right angle to the vertex I haven't mentioned yet.